# Sorting of author names like "von Beethoven" with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I wonder how I can get a proper sorting of names in the bibliography.

In the following example, "von Beethoven" is at the position "v", but it should be sorted as "Beethoven" under "B".

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib4.bib}

@MISC{Volkmann,
  author = {Volkmann, Albert},
  title = {title},
  year = {2005},
}

@MISC{vonBeethoven2005,
  author = {von Beethoven, Ludwig},
  title = {title},
  year = {2005},
}

@MISC{Caesar,
  author = {Caesar, Gaius J.},
  title = {title},
  year = {2005},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[color, draft]{showkeys} %Einblenden der Referenznamen in den Arbeitsversionen
\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{\fbox{\normalfont\tiny\ttfamily#1}} 
\definecolor{refkey}{cmyk}{0.26,0,0.76,0}%{gray}{0.5} 
\definecolor{labelkey}{cmyk}{0.26,0,0.76,0}%{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{grau}{gray}{0.5}

\usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp, backend=bibtex8, defernumbers, useprefix, maxnames=99, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}  % fÂ¸r bessere Literaturverzeichnisse
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}
\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\addsemicolon\space}


\usepackage{csquotes} 

\bibliography{mybib4}

\begin{document}

citeauthor: \citeauthor{vonBeethoven2005} 

Citeauthor: \Citeauthor{vonBeethoven2005}

\cite{vonBeethoven2005}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could add `sortname={Beethoven}` to your bib entry. But maybe there even is an automated solution?

Comment: Just to be entirely correct, the composer and pianist was Ludwig _van_ Beethoven.

Comment: He must be talking about a different Beethoven: the Ludwig _von_ Beethoven, author of the famous work "_title_" from 2005

Comment: @Seamus I actually typed it into Google before realising that it was a joke. :-D (I did not read the MWE before commenting.)

Comment: @HarroldCavendish: I know, I just needed a quick example, and my problematic real name in the bibliography contains a "von" and not a "van", but I did not want to use the real citation. Sorry for the very stupid example, but it is real "minimal" :-D

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't forget that many options in biblatex/biber are per-entry so you can just add:

```
OPTIONS = {useprefix=false}
```

to the entry. Table 2 in the Biber manual and Appendix C of the BibLaTeX manual detail which options have which scope - with Biber, many options can have global, per-entrytype or per-entry scope. This actually makes quite a few surprising things possible.

Answer (score 19):

You could simply omit the `useprefix` option -- and this will also produce "Beethoven" instead of "von Beethoven" in citations (as it should for the sake of consistency). To sort the composer under "Beethoven" and at the same time use the prefix when citing, keep `useprefix` and add a `sortkey` field to the entry in your `.bib` file:

```
@MISC{vonBeethoven2005,
  author = {von Beethoven, Ludwig},
  sortkey= {Beethoven, Ludwig von},
  title = {title},
  year = {2005},
}
```

See also [Biblatex, capitalization of arabic names and name prefixes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6941/biblatex-capitalization-of-arabic-names-and-name-prefixes).

Comment: Is it really good style to keep "von" in citations and not using it for sorting?

Comment: The linked question about arabic names/name prefixes has taught me not to think about "style" too much when it comes to citing vs. sorting.

Comment: Yes, but this is a German name in a German document.

Comment: I'd try to be consistent, i.e. use "von" for both citing/sorting, or for none of them. However, inconsistency in this regard doesn't give me the creeps like, say, `\doublespacing`. :-)

Comment: @egreg: Are you suggesting that "von" be dropped entirely?

Comment: @Werner I'm suggesting to follow the main national style, at least for local people's names. It would be annoying for a reader not finding a name in the bibliography where it belongs according to the citation.

Comment: @egreg: Answer rephrased.

Comment: @lockstep: thanks for pointing out the `sortkey` alternative. For the moment I'll stick with the `useprefix=true` option.

Comment: In general, German and Dutch standard is to have von/van in the citations but alphabetize under the following name in the biblipgrahpy (see [http://kaivonfintel.org/von/]). So using  both `userprefix` and `sortkey` gets the right order usage pattern **except** for the fact that the van/von prefix is capitalized. To overcome this we can write `{von}` in the `author` field. This would solve the problem of capitalization in the bibliography, but will still get a wrong result when our cited author starts a sentence, in which case _von_ **should** be capitalized!

Comment: Just for completeness: Belgian usage, contrary to Dutch one, is to treat the _Van_ part as part of the family name: i.e., always capitalize and sort under V.

Answer (score 17):

The `useprefix` option just tells `biblatex` that "von" must be considered as part of the last name for citing and sorting.

```
\usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp,
  backend=bibtex8, defernumbers,
  % useprefix, % <- von is part of last name with this option
  maxnames=99, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}
```

(Page 60 of the manual.)