# Name prefix missing in the text, but correct in the bibliography (biblatex/biber)

Tags: biblatex

The following is my entry in the `.bib` file:

```
@inbook{deckerdejong,
  author = {Wolfram Decker and Theo de Jong},
    title = {Gr\"obner bases and invariant theory},
    booktitle = {Gr\"obner Bases and Applications},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    year = 1998,
    pages = "61-89"
}
```

Now when I quote this in the text by `\citet{deckerdejong}`, I get "Decker and Jong (1998)" as output. But I need it to be "Decker and de Jong (1998)". How do I accomplish this? I already tried out some answers of the ["van noort" example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40747/18674), but they didn't work for me. I use `biblatex` with the `authoryear` style and biber.

Comment: My knee-jerk is to either enclose `{de Jong}` or tie `de~Jong`.  Do either of those work?

Comment: It would also be great if you could say, *which* of the answers from the "van noort example" you already tried. You should also take into account, that this example is about bibtex while your question is about biblatex and biber which might work different in some points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the package option `useprefix=true`. Note that the prefix will be used in citations *and* for sorting the bibliography; if you don't want the latter, see [How can I put a name's prefix in front in citations but *not* in the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21361/how-can-i-put-a-names-prefix-in-front-in-citations-but-not-in-the-bibliograph) and [Sorting of author names like "von Beethoven" with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39955/sorting-of-author-names-like-von-beethoven-with-biblatex).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,useprefix=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{deckerdejong,
  author = {Wolfram Decker and Theo de Jong},
    title = {Gr\"obner bases and invariant theory},
    booktitle = {Gr\"obner Bases and Applications},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    year = 1998,
    pages = "61-89"
}
@misc{dejong,
  author = {Theo de Jong},
  title = {Delta},
  year = {2004},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

As shown in \textcite{deckerdejong}~\dots

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]