# Citing "von lastname", "von lastname" in bibliography, but sort by "lastname"

Tags: biblatex

I am using `\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, useprefix=true]{biblatex}`

I am aware that with the `useprefix` option I can turn on/off using the "von" for both citations and bibliography.
However, I want to use "von lastname" in both but sort by "lastname" in the bibliography. "von" preferably in lowercase.
This seems to be possible with adding `sortkey = {lastname, firstname von}` to each entry (like in this post: [Sorting of author names like "von Beethoven" with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39955/sorting-of-author-names-like-von-beethoven-with-biblatex)).

But I am importing my .bib file from Zotero, so I cannot modify it manually (e.g. to add a field).

I would go so far as to add "sortkey = lastname, firstname von" in Zotero somehow, but I don't see how this would be possible. It doesn't seem to work in the Extra field.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440133/35864. It requires no change on the `.bib` file level.

Comment: Any news here? As your question stands now, I would say it is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440133/35864, but a quick confirmation would be great.